# loosing the tmux session when ssh connection is discunnected

Tags: macos, ssh, tmux

I am using `macOS BigSur`. And I am running a script on a gpu on a remote machine using a ssh tunnel. Since the process is long I am using `tmux` and I want the process continues running when I disconnect from `ssh`. But the problem is that when ssh is disconnected, the `tmux session` is also killed.

What I do is as follows:

1- ssh into the remote machine

2- start tmux by typing tmux into the shell

3- start the process inside the started tmux session

4- leave/detach the tmux session by typing Ctrl+b and then d

But once I do that, when I come back and I connect to ssh I find that the process is killed.
Any help is really appreciated. I need to run a script for 3000 epochs and because of this problem I can't.

Comment: Did you try to run `tmux ls` to see open sessions and the attaching to the session with `tmux attach-session -t session_name/number`? If you can't maybe server killed tmux, try running `ps` to see if tmux is running, if it is killed then all sessions are terminated. If it is running you can try to recreate its socket by sending `USR1` signal, `pkill -USR1 tmux`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what's happening to you, but I find that when I ssh with the -X flag, then some processes (python3 and matlab, which I run in the terminal) die when I disconnect.

But if I just do ssh with no -X flag, they survive the disconnect.

Comment: Would `-x` differ from `-X`?

Comment: `-x` disables X11 forwarding, while `-X` enables it. You could also check out the `-y` and `-Y` options in the ssh manpage: `man ssh`